# building a webscraper with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the job resutls of a website (jobs.at) with beautifulsoup and once i am starting to loop over the results, I only get a list of the first result. Could you help me to get a list of all search results?

```
jobs = []

for search_result in soup.find_all('div', class_="c-search-results"):
    
    job_name = soup.find("h2", class_="c-job-headline j-u-typo-m j-u-font-weight-bold j-u-margin-bottom-3xs").a.text
    
    jobs.append({'job_name': job_name})
    
print(jobs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you were unpacking the 1st list but not the 2nd one.
Basically you have to use the find_all twice otherwise you will get only the 1st result.
Please consider this is basically pseudo-code, if you provide a working example I can help better.

```
jobs = []

for search_result in soup.find_all('div', class_="c-search-results"):
    for job_name in soup.find_all("h2", class_="c-job-headline j-u-typo-m j-u-font-weight-bold j-u-margin-bottom-3xs"):
        job_name = job_name.a.text
        print(job_name) # This is the added line
        jobs.append({'job_name': job_name})
    
print(jobs)
```

Comment: Awesome, this actually worked already. The problem now is that after the 15th search result, the website posts an ad in between the 15th and 16th job result. Is there a way to iterate over the ad and continue with the jobs results?

Comment: Please create a specific question with this providing details and you will get specific help.
If my answer helped you solving the question you discussed here please consider upvoting it and / or selecting it as final answer.

Comment: I think you can just check the ad text with length or regex and skip the entry.

Comment: Hi @Pitto, the html code of the ad is the following: 

<form method="POST" action="https://www.jobs.at/jobalarm" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="c-job-alarm-form j-c-card j-u-margin-bottom-xl j-u-overflow-hidden j-u-background-color-cyan-50" data-logged-in="false" novalidate data-form-name="job-alarm-form">…</form>

How would you change my code with your proposed solution? Sorry for the basic stuff, I am still quite the beginner

Comment: No worries...
I will edit my script above adding a debug line.
Please paste the data printed out by the ad using that line.

Comment: I believe the problem is another in the end. I think that job.at is an infinite scrolling page that reloads after every 15 search results. Do you have an idea how to deal with infinite scrolling pages? Thanks a lot for your help @Pitto

Comment: There a solution for every problem, clearly.
Please provide a [mcve] and create a specific question.